# How to do mutual certificate authentication with httplib2

Tags: python, ssl, httplib2

I'm using httplib2 to make a request from my server to another web service.  We want to use mutual certificate authentication.  I see how to use a certificate for the outgoing connection (`h.set_certificate`), but how do I check the certificate used by the answering server?

[This ticket](http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/issues/detail?id=4) seems to indicate that httplib2 doesn't do it itself, and has only vague suggestions about where to look.

Is it possible?  Am I going to have to hack at a lower level?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the code my co-worker Dave St. Germain wrote to solve the problem:

```
import ssl
import socket
from httplib2 import has_timeout
import httplib2
import socks


class CertificateValidationError(httplib2.HttpLib2Error):
    pass


def validating_sever_factory(ca_cert_file):
    # we need to define a closure here because we don't control
    # the arguments this class is instantiated with
    class ValidatingHTTPSConnection(httplib2.HTTPSConnectionWithTimeout):

        def connect(self):
            # begin copypasta from HTTPSConnectionWithTimeout
            "Connect to a host on a given (SSL) port."

            if self.proxy_info and self.proxy_info.isgood():
                sock = socks.socksocket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                sock.setproxy(*self.proxy_info.astuple())
            else:
                sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

            if has_timeout(self.timeout):
                sock.settimeout(self.timeout)
            sock.connect((self.host, self.port))
            # end copypasta


            try:
                self.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock,
                            self.key_file,
                            self.cert_file,
                            cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED,
                            ca_certs=ca_cert_file
                            )
            except ssl.SSLError:
                # we have to capture the exception here and raise later because 
                # httplib2 tries to ignore exceptions on connect
                import sys
                self._exc_info = sys.exc_info()
                raise
            else:
                self._exc_info = None

                # this might be redundant
                server_cert = self.sock.getpeercert()
                if not server_cert:
                    raise CertificateValidationError(repr(server_cert))

        def getresponse(self):
            if not self._exc_info:
                return httplib2.HTTPSConnectionWithTimeout.getresponse(self)
            else:
                raise self._exc_info[1], None, self._exc_info[2]
    return ValidatingHTTPSConnection


def do_request(url,
        method='GET',
        body=None,
        headers=None,
        keyfile=None,
        certfile=None,
        ca_certs=None,
        proxy_info=None,
        timeout=30):
    """
    makes an http/https request, with optional client certificate and server
    certificate verification.
    returns response, content
    """
    kwargs = {}
    h = httplib2.Http(proxy_info=proxy_info, timeout=timeout)
    is_ssl = url.startswith('https')
    if is_ssl and ca_certs:
        kwargs['connection_type'] = validating_sever_factory(ca_certs)

    if is_ssl and keyfile and certfile:
        h.add_certificate(keyfile, certfile, '')
    return h.request(url, method=method, body=body, headers=headers, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 2):

perhaps things have changed since your question, I am able to do mutual authentication with [httplib2](http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/) v0.7, as below:

```
import httplib2

h=httplib2.Http(ca_certs='ca.crt')
h.add_certificate(key='client_private_key.pem', cert='cert_client.pem', domain='')
try: resp, cont = h.request('https://mytest.com/cgi-bin/test.cgi')
except Exception as e: print e
```

Note the `domain=''` argument, this is the only way I could make it work

Comment: According to [this link](http://nullege.com/codes/search/httplib2.Http.add_certificate), `domain` must be just a hostname and port.